# How can I read a file and redirect it to a variable?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a file with a word written on it. I want my script to put that word in a variable.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

in several of a million ways...

simplest is probably

```
my_var=$(cat my_file)
```

If you use bash and you want to get spiffy you can use bash4's mapfile, which puts an entire file into an array variable, one line per cell

```
mapfile my_var < my_file
```

Comment: newlines will make the first part try to execute and fail with a command not found error use var=$(cat file | tr -d '\n') to remove all new lines, including any trailing ones

Comment: @Jonathan no it won't

Comment: Be careful when using this with a single-line file. The resulting *array* variable will look like a normal one, but you won't be able to easily export it: `echo X > f; mapfile -t V < f; echo V is $V; export V; env | grep V=`. Note how `V` is missing from `env` despite being defined before exporting.

Answer (score 58):

The simplest way is probably:

```
var=$(< file)
```

which doesn't create a new process.

Comment: This works in Bash and other advanced shells, but not in the Bourne shell.

Comment: not cross platform... won't work in sh see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427262/how-to-read-a-file-into-a-variable-in-shell

Comment: Does anyone/anything even still use non-bash sh in 2018? Maybe Dick Tracy's watch??

Comment: Warning: no space prior to the _“<”_ (i.e. _“`(<`”_ instead of _“`( <`”_).

Comment: This solution does a transformation over 'endline' char on linux.

Answer (score 4):

```
var="`cat /path/to/file`"
```

This is the simple way. Be careful with newlines in the file.

```
var="`head -1 /path/to/file`"
```

This will only get the first line and will never include a newline.

Comment: I have a file nammed "log", and `$x="\`cat log\`"` results in `=2: command not found`

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way is something like

```
$ myvar=`cat file`
```

Comment: It's not necessary to export the variable and the spaces around the equal sign won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will strip newlines, but here it is anyway:

```
variable=$(cat filename)
```

Comment: It will only strip the final newline. If you seem to be getting the other newlines stripped, it's because you're not quoting the variable on output. `echo $variable` vs. `echo "$variable"`