# save a text file in a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

how can I read a text file and save it to a variable in bash ? my code is here :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
TEXT="dummy"
echo "Please, enter your project name"
read PROJECT_NAME  
mkdir $PROJECT_NAME  
cp -r -f /home/reza/Templates/Template\ Project/* $PROJECT_NAME  
cd $PROJECT_NAME/Latest  
TEXT = `cat configure.ac `  ## problem is here   !!!  
CHANGED_TEXT=${TEXT//ProjectName/$PROJECT_NAME}
echo $CHANGED_TEXT
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [read a file and save it in variable using shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427262/read-a-file-and-save-it-in-variable-using-shell-script)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue is that you have an extra space. Assignment requires zero spaces between the `=` operator.  However, with `bash` you can use:

```
TEXT=$(<configure.ac)
```

You'll also want to make sure you quote your variables to preserve newlines

```
CHANGED_TEXT="${TEXT//ProjectName/$PROJECT_NAME}"
echo "$CHANGED_TEXT"
```

Comment: it worked but it has a problem :the lines are missing .all the characters become in just 1 line like [this](http://paste.kde.org/200162/) what I should do ?

Comment: @reza did you quote your variables like I mentioned?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
TEXT=`cat configure.ac`
```

That should work.

Edit:

To clarify, the difference is in the spacing: putting a space after `TEXT` causes bash to try to look it up as a command.

Answer (score 2):

For execute a command and return the result in bash script for save in a variable, for example, you must write the command inner to var=$(command). And you mustn't give spaces between var,'=' and $(). Look at this

```
TEXT=$('cat configure.ac')
```

Now, `echo $TEXT` return the content by file configure.ac.