# Read entire file to variable, keeping escaped characters intact

Tags: bash, shell, echo, zsh

Suppose I have the following file:

```
hello\nworld
```

That is, the string `\n` is literally present in the file:

```
$ cat input.txt
hello\nworld
```

I want to read this file exactly like it is into a variable in the shell. However, all common approaches for reading the data from a file, like those described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984432/how-to-read-the-file-content-into-a-variable-in-one-go), make the shell interpret the `\n` sequence as a newline:

```
% test="$(<input.txt)"
% echo "$test"        
hello
world
% test="$(cat input.txt)"
% echo "$test"
hello
world
```

This was completely unexpected to me, and frankly I'm confused that I cannot find an answer to this problem on the internet; I expected that someone already tripped over this problem.

I also saw that if you use `read -r` when reading a file line by line, it works, but I don't want to read it line by line, I want to read the entire file. Concretely, I want the `test` variable here contain the string "hello\nworld" literally. How do I do it?

Comment: Is your `echo` aliased to `echo -e` maybe?

Comment: @gudok no, it is not.

Comment: What do `type echo` and `which echo` tell?

Comment: Both print that they are shell builtins. But it seems the correct answer is that zsh somehow has a different idea of what echo should be by default.

Comment: Reading the file isn't the problem; `echo` is, because `zsh` follows the POSIX spec to expand `\n` but `bash` doesn't. Use `printf '%s' "$test"` instead.

Comment: You can use VAR=`cat file`
Cat shouldn't exapnd special characters

Comment: @Yarden above is correct. the backticks don't show, but this is the same: `VAR=$(cat file)` -- i.e. `test=$(cat input.txt)`

Comment: instead of echo "$test" try cat <<< "$test"

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk There is little point running a separate program when a built-in command will suffice.

Comment: @chepner:  Thanks.  You are right that built in's are generally better.  It may even be better in this case.  The performance hit for this command that is being used to manually inspect what is happening is tiny.  Some bash people are not C programmers so the printf syntax, though in bash, is really a carry over from C and may be less clear than cat which gets used a lot.  I would chalk this up to debuggers prerogative.  I think that both methods get this job done, but your performance may be worse with cat for very large strings and no console IO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably use `read -r -d '' <input.txt` to read the whole file in a single string.

However, in my tests, I am not getting this behaviour.  Maybe your `echo` does that interpretation.  Try `printf "%s" "$test"` to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Wow, indeed printf trick did work, so looks like `$(<file)` works correctly. It seems that this is indeed a problem with echo. That said, I now remembered that I actually use zsh instead of bash, maybe it happens because of zsh.

Comment: Yes, I found in zsh documentation that by default `echo` expands the escape characters, and a `-E` option has to be provided to turn this off.