# make environmental variable equal the contents of a file

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I am working on linux and I want to set an environmental variable to the contents of a file:
vi file:

```
the env var should equal everything in here
```

Now the file has a lot of " and other special characters and it will a take a lot of time to escape them all. Is there an easier way?

Comment: I think this question is almost an exact duplicate and has better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427262/how-to-read-a-file-into-a-variable-in-shell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file into a variable in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427262/how-to-read-a-file-into-a-variable-in-shell)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If filename is `x.txt`, you can use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to set the content of that file as an environment variable.

```
export C=$(cat x.txt)
```

Comment: Please explain why this would work instead of just giving an answer.

Comment: A more recent syntax is `export C=$(cat x.txt)` and `$(`...`)` is more readable and is nestable.

Comment: The `$(...)` shell construct runs the shell command inside the parentheses. Another way of doing this you may have seen before is to delimit with backticks. The command is then substituted for its own output, which is then assigned to the environment variable, in this case `C`.

Comment: Actually a preferred way to do this with bash is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10771857): `export VARIABLE=$(<filename.txt)`. The answer has further advice in the comments which will help avoid some gotchas.