# Cron Job Killing and Restarting Python Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I set up a cron job on a linux server to kill and restart a python script (run.py) every other day. I set the job to run as root, but I find that sometimes it doesn't kill the process properly (and ends up running two scripts in a row).

Is there a better way to do this?

My cron job parameters:

`0 8 * * 1,4,7 cd /home/myUser && ./start.sh`

start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running..."
sudo pkill -f run.py
sudo python run.py &
```

Comment: The script should probably have a shebang.

Comment: Good point, when I copied over the script to this I missed that part out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `run.py` runs as `python`, not `run.py`. So you won't find anything with `kill -f run.py`.

You should echo the PID of the process to a file and use that value to kill the previous process if it's still running. Just add `echo $! >/path/to/pid.file` as the last line in your `start.sh` script to do so.

Read more:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/205498/how-to-get-pid-of-just-started-process
- [How to read a file into a variable in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427262/read-a-file-into-a-variable)
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/kill-process-in-linux-or-terminate-a-process-in-unix-or-linux-systems/

---

Example to get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running..."
sudo pkill -F /path/to/pid.pid
sudo python /path/to/run.py &
echo $! > /path/to/pid.pid
```

Comment: do i need the sudo ?

Comment: @GeorgePamfilis for `pkill`, only if the process was started by another user than the user starting the cron. For `python`, only if the script requires elevated permissions. Good practice: start without, add if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to this is making the python script run on upstart if you are on a system that supports upstart. Then you can just do `sudo /sbin/start job_name` at the begin and `sudo /sbin/stop job_name` this makes upstart manage the pids for you.

Python upstart script
[Upstart python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814357/upstart-python-script)