# Upstart python script

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, upstart

I need to run code located */home/pi/Hello_on_startup.py* each time RaspberryPi restarts

For that I created hello.conf file in */etc/init/* directory

```
description "A script controlled by upstart"
author "Anton"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

exec /home/pi/Hello_on_startup.py`
```

When I run command *sudo start hello* I get an answer *Unknown job: hello*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `script...end script` block in your conf file for it to be recognised, as shown [here](http://infovore.org/archives/2013/08/09/running-scripts-on-startup-with-your-raspberry-pi/). Your resulting `hello.conf` file would look as follows:

```
description "A script controlled by upstart"
author "Anton"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

script
    exec /home/pi/Hello_on_startup.py`
end script
```

There is also a similar question on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247077/upstart-is-not-seeing-my-new-script).