# Reading an entire file into a variable in a C-Shell (csh) Script

Tags: shell, csh

I need to read an entire text file into a shell variable.  There is already another thread on this, but it only gives examples for sh and bash:

[How to read a file into a variable in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427262/how-to-read-a-file-into-a-variable-in-shell)

How do I do this in csh?

Sorry for starting a new thread, but I'm new to this site and couldn't comment. How are you supposed to build up your reputation if you can't comment to begin with?

Comment: Did you try the mentioned methods? Did it work?

Comment: I did, but it did not work.  I think in csh you have to use the "set" command.  I tried the following, but that did not work either:  set value=`cat config.txt` and set value=$(<config.txt)

Comment: What are you trying to solve?  Perhaps just keep a variable with the filename, and use that instead?

Comment: I think it's quite likely that csh lacks the syntax to do it, and there's no way to do it externally, either, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell

Comment: I need to insert the contents of config.txt into a C-shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
set value=`cat myfile`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
setenv VAR `cat my_file`
```

If you want use it for concat a variable (that is my need):

```
setenv VAR `cat my_file`$VAR
```