# Bash: Variable from file output

Tags: bash, shell

I use a script on my personal server to setup a few things, and I'm a bit lazy. 
So instead of doing every command by hand etc I got this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshservers=(IP IP IP IP)
for sshserver in "${sshservers[@]}"
        do
        ssh root@$sshserver 'Foo Bar'
done
echo "done"
exit
```

So it takes the servers from the variable in sshservers=.
But I want it to take the IP's from a file called "servers.txt".
Though when using

```
sshservers=$(cat servers.txt)
```

This doesn't work. I have to manually insert it directly in the script. 
How can I use the variable from a text file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427262/how-to-read-a-file-into-a-variable-in-shell

Comment: `sshservers=($(<servers.txt))`?

Comment: Hi @123, that works perfect, thank you!

Comment: @123 maybe you could post it as an answer so this question can be marked solved.. thnx!

Comment: @SB87 its a duplicate but i can't be bothered finding the original