# Read file into variable while suppressing "No such file or directory" error

Tags: bash

I want to read text file contents into a Bash variable, suppressing the error message if that file does not exist. In POSIX, I would do

```
var=$(cat file 2>/dev/null)
```

But I read (e.g. at [How to read a file into a variable in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427262/how-to-read-a-file-into-a-variable-in-shell)) that it's a *Useless Use of Cat* in Bash. So, I'm trying those:

```
var=$(< file 2>/dev/null)
var=$(< file) 2>/dev/null
```

But it the first doesn't read an existing file, and both print `-bash: file: No such file or directory` if the file does not exist. **Why doesn't this work?** (Especially: What completely breaks the first one?)

What does work is this:

```
{ var=$(< file); } 2>/dev/null
```

But it's ugly and cumbersome. So, **is there a nicer syntax, or is this a valid use of cat after all?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirection applies to the output of a command line. When the `cat` command produces an error, you can redirect the stderr as you've done.

But when you generate the error within the command line itself, through input redirection from a file that doesn't exist, THAT shell is the one producing the error, and you're not redirecting its output to anywhere special. You've successfully discovered the "ugly and cumbersome" workaround, which mimics a subshell using curly braces.

Personally, I'd use an `if` construct, but if you really prefer shorter code over fewer calls to external programs, this is a perfectly valid use of `cat`.

Comment: Thanks. I chose your answer (even though it has received fewer votes) because it not just provides an opinion, but also explains the behavior I'd seen.

Answer (score 9):

With BASH it is easy to test if file exists before reading it in

```
[ -e file ] && var=$(< file )
```

As Inian points in the comments the file might exist but the user might not have sufficient rights for reading it. The `-r` test would take care of that.

```
[ -r file ] && var=$(< file )
```

Comment: Does this handle the error stream when the file exists and permission is denied for the file?

Comment: True, but isn't this even worse than my alternatives: 1. Additional check and code branch (and potential race condition if the file vanishes between the two) 2. Issues with `-e` vs. `-r` (as @Inian also commented on) 3. Need to initialize `var=` in addition 4. Probably (slightly) worse performance

Comment: Poor performance is baked into the shell :) Don't worry about unavoidable and negligible things like this.

Comment: @chepner: Sure, that's why I put it last in my list (just for completeness :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
var=$(cat file 2>/dev/null)
```

This is a *Useful Use of Cat*. It enforces an order of operations: stderr is redirected before `file` is opened. It serves a purpose. Don't feel bad about using it.

Answer (score 0):

Define a commands block with curly braces and redirect the `stderr` to `/dev/null` for the whole block.

```sh
{ IFS= read -rd '' var <file;} 2>/dev/null
```