# How to display a diff of two files in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, diff

I'm trying to compare the contents of two files in a bash script.

```
local_file=$(cat my_local_file.txt)
remote_file=$(curl -s "http://example.com/remote-file.txt")

if [ local_file == remote_file ]; then
  echo "Files are the same"
else
  echo "Files are different. Here is the diff:"
  diff <(echo "$local_file") <(echo "$remote_file")
fi
```

When I run the script, I see that I have a syntax error:

```
./bin/check_files.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./bin/check_files.sh: line 8: `  diff <(echo "$local_file") <(echo "$remote_file")'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I display a diff of these two strings from a bash script?

Comment: It's probably a better idea to download the file locally, rather than hold it in memory in Bash. In particular `$(...)` [doesn't preserve trailing newlines or NUL characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22607352/113632), so the contents of `local_file` and `remote_file` could potentially not reflect what's on-disk.

Comment: @dimo414 Does `diff` deal with NUL characters? I suspect not.

Comment: @Barmar I can't say universally, since there are different implementations, but I'd consider any `diff` program that fails to do so broken. GNU diff does indeed work with NUL characters, try `diff <(printf 'foo\0bar') <(printf 'foo\0\0bar')`.

Comment: @dimo414 I don't think POSIX requires utilities that process text files to deal with embedded NUL characters. Many GNU utilities try to go beyond the requirements, but it's not something I would generally expect.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure if this is a canonical source, but it looks like [POSIX `diff`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/diff/) (see "Diff Binary Output Format") explicitly supports binary files.

Comment: @dimo414 Which basically says that if they're not text files, it becomes more like `cmp`.

Comment: Sure - but it doesn't silently discard `NUL`s, which is what Bash does and what you originally objected to.

Answer (score 5):

[Process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) is a bash feature, which is usually not available in `/bin/sh` which is meant to be POSIX compatible.

Make sure to use the following shebang line if you want to run the script as an executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

instead of

```
#!/bin/sh
```

or use

```
bash script.sh
```

instead of

```
sh script.sh
```

if you run it like that

---

To make the script work with POSIX conform shells I would just download the file and compare it against the local file. Remove the downloaded file after the diff.

Comment: Process substitution isn't even available in bash if it's run under the name "sh"; therefore, you *must* explicitly use "bash" instead of "sh" (preferably via the shebang, but running the script with `bash scriptname` would also work).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `<(command)` (process substitution) syntax issue, your code `if [ local_file == remote_file ]` compares the literal strings `local_file` and `remote_file`, rather than the content of the variables.  You need `$local_file` and `$remote_file` to compare the contents.  Need to enclose them in double quotes to prevent word splitting issues.

You could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

local_file=$(< my_local_file.txt) # this is more efficient than $(cat file)
remote_file=$(curl -s "http://example.com/remote-file.txt")

if [ "$local_file" = "$remote_file" ]; then
  echo "Files are the same"
else
  echo "Files are different. Here is the diff:"
  diff <(printf '%s' "$local_file") <(printf '%s' "$remote_file")
fi
```

As stated by @dimo414, the limitation here is that the command substitution `$(...)` removes trailing newlines and that would cause a problem.  So, it is better to download the remote file and compare it with the local file:

```
local_file=my_local_file.txt
curl -s "http://example.com/remote-file.txt" -o remote_file

if diff=$(diff -- "$local_file" remote_file); then
  echo "Files are the same"
else
  echo "Files are different. Here is the diff:"
  printf '%s' "$diff"
fi
```

Comment: diff's return value tells you if the inputs match, so you could get by without the cmp call. Something like this should work and be slightly quicker.

`local_file=my_local_file.txt
curl -s "http://example.com/remote-file.txt" -o remote_file

OUTPUT=$( diff -- "$local_file" "$remote_file" )

if [ $? ];
  echo "Files are the same"
else
  echo "Files are different. Here is the diff:"
  echo "$OUTPUT"
fi`

Comment: In your initial  description and code, `if [ "$a" = "$b" ]; then` compares the strings also?

curl would download to the file called `remote_file`, so the cmp line should  be `if cmp -s -- "$local_file" "remote_file"; then`

Comment: Thanks @RyanPrescott. Updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the following command:

```
cmp -b "File_1.txt" "File_2.txt"
```

Comment: How does this help when the file data is in variables?