# What is the difference between "$(cat file)", "$(<file)" and "read ... < file" for files with one line?

Tags: bash, file, strace

I have an input file that contains only one line:

```
$ cat input
foo bar
```

I want to use this line in my script and there are 3 ways to get it that I know of:

```
line=$(cat input)
```

```
line=$(<input)
```

```
IFS= read -r line < input
```

---

For example, using command substitution means I spawn a subshell, whereas with `read` I do not, correct? What other differences are there and is one way preferred over the others? I also noticed (with `strace`) that only `read` triggers the syscall `openat` for some reason. How is it possible that the others don't?

```
$ strace ./script |& grep input
read(3, "#!/usr/bin/env bash\n\ncat > input"..., 80) = 80
read(255, "#!/usr/bin/env bash\n\ncat > input"..., 167) = 167
read(255, "\nline=$(cat input)\nline=$(<input"..., 167) = 60
read(255, "line=$(<input)\nIFS= read -r line"..., 167) = 41
read(255, "IFS= read -r line < input\n", 167) = 26
openat(AT_FDCWD, "input", O_RDONLY)     = 3
```

Comment: *"that only `read` triggers the syscall openat for some reason. How is it possible that the others don't?"* -- as you already know, the first two commands read the file in a sub-shell. Make sure you ask `strace` to also trace the child processes spawn by the initial process you trace.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- `line=$(cat input)` is the POSIX way of reading the entire file. It requires a fork.
- `line=$(< input)` is a marginally more efficient Bashism for reading the entire file. It also forks, but doesn't have to execve.
- Not mentioned but `mapfile`/`readarray` are significantly more efficient Bashisms for reading the entire file line-by-line into arrays. No forks.
- `IFS= read -r line < input` is the POSIX way of reading a single line without a subshell. No forks.

The reason why you only see the latter opening the file is simply that the others do it in a subshell, and you haven't specified `-f` to trace child processes.

Comment: Heh. I was under the mistaken impression that `$(<...)` was all in-process, but you're quite right that it forks. That said, it's certainly possible for a future bash release to no longer do so, and thus to provide a much more efficient implementation -- using the POSIX syntax is thus locking one into not just the `exec` but also the `fork`, whereas `$(<...)` can be improved to do neither in the future.

Comment: Interesting. Does that mean `read -rd '' wholefile < somefile` is (for now) more efficient than `wholefile=$(< somefile)`, even with `read`'s byte-scanning overhead?