# reading a line from file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have store ip address with port in a file and I want to read it using shell script. Thus file `serverIP` has data `192.168.1.17:3000`. I am using following bash script to read it

```
IPAddressFile=/home/geo/serverIP
SERVER_IP_PORT=$(<$IPAddressFile)
echo $SERVER_IP_PORT
```

But this script `echo` empty string. Where I am making mistake?

Comment: Can't replicate with the commands you show. Did you copy-paste the script into the question? If not, is everything spelled correctly in the script?

Comment: Possible duplicate. Please refer to this anser: [How to read a file into a variable in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10771857)

Comment: No I am following the same code in given accepted answer but it's not working my case and that's why I have posted this question

Comment: How are you running the script? If you run `sh yourscript` it won't have bash-only extensions such as `$(<...)`; it *must* be invoked with bash as the shell.

Comment: Yes I am running `sh scriptfile`

Comment: Don't. If you want to use bash syntax, you must `bash scriptfile`, or set it executable with a `#!/bin/bash` shebang and run `./scriptfile`.

Comment: Thanks Charles this is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use bash-only syntax like `$(<...)`, your script must be run with bash, not sh.

Thus, either run `bash yourscript` or add a `#!/bin/bash` (or similar) shebang, flag the file executable, and invoke it as a command, for example `./yourscript`

---

As an alternative that's both efficient and compatible with POSIX sh:

```
IFS= read -r SERVER_IP_PORT <"$IPAddressFile"
```

Comment: What? Charles Duffy is not using `"${IPAddressFile}"`?

Comment: @hek2mgl, ...when did I ever support use of braces in contexts where they're  not necessary for correctness or clarity? You must be thinking of someone else. :)

Comment: hihi. didn't know that this is your opinion on that :) I mean yeah, they are unnecessary here (which required _me_ a test), but isn't it a good practice to always use them? (It's also good for the muscles of your fingers btw, at least on a German keyboard)

Comment: ...now, what *is* unlike me is failing to lecture the OP about their use of all-caps names for self-defined variables :)

Comment: ...but re: "good practice to always use them", there's not a prevailing opinion either way that I'm aware of. Sometimes they *must* be used -- if you're concatenating an expansion with trailing characters that are valid in variable names; or if you want to parameterize your expansion -- but otherwise it's a style choice.

Comment: I was thinking that when people just consequently use them, they will never have to spent time thinking about if they have to use them, or forget them. And it gives a cleaner overall picture of the code.

Comment: *nod*, that's a very defensible position; I certainly won't say you're wrong. OTOH, most of the shell scripts I write outside Stack Overflow these days are being embedded in [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) code, and Nix uses `${...}` as an escape to embed a Nix expression in a string unless escaped as `''${...}` -- so it'd be a bit painful to follow that convention in my real-world day-to-day.