# How do I correctly read in a file with sh scripting and using it in an if statement?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

So there is a kernel adiutor for android, that let's you add custom controls with shell scripting. I'm trying to add a switch, but I have trouble setting the switch up correctly, when it's active, and when it's not. So there is a (text)file I'm trying to read (you will see it in the code), whether it's 0 or 1 inside, and that determines the switch on-off state.

I've tried with cat, read, everything, but honestly I think the problem is that I'm not familiar with sh scripting, and there is a problem with my syntax. Sometimes the script won't return anything when using cat. Also, su is available so that's not a problem, also the file has the correct permissions.

```
#!/system/bin/sh
var= $(<sys/class/lcd/panel/mdnie/hdr)
if (  "$var" = 0) then
    echo 0
    else echo 1
fi
```

The problem with my code is that right now it returns 1 (on), even when the file has a 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When assigning a variable in shell, there must be no space after the assignment sign. Also, make sure you use the correct syntax for conditions (and be aware of whitespace sensitivity):

```sh
var=$(cat sys/class/lcd/panel/mdnie/hdr)
if [ "$var" = "0" ]; then
# if [ "$var" -eq 0 ], if you want numeric comparison (won't really matter here)
    echo 0
else
    echo 1
fi
```

Comment: @tripleee not in `bash` or `zsh` :) but I have adapted the script to work in any POSIX shell

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say this is not `sh` but would work in Bash or Zsh.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427262/how-to-read-a-file-into-a-variable-in-shell