# How can I ignore errors with bash stdin redirection?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I want to read a file into a variable. I can do this with a [stdin redirection operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427262/how-to-read-a-file-into-a-variable-in-shell):

```
MYVAR=$(</some/file)
```

However, the file is a sysfs node and may error out. I'm also using `set -o errtrace` and want to ignore the error if it happens, just getting an empty variable. I've tried the following but surprisingly it always gives an empty variable.

```
MYVAR=$(</some/file || true)
```

Why is it always empty?

I could use `cat`:

```
MYVAR=$(cat /some/file 2>/dev/null || true)
```

but would like to know if it's possible without.

Comment: What do you want to do if it errors out? What do you expect to store in the variable?

Comment: Just an empty variable. The node doesn't write anything to stdout if there is an error so that's what I'm hoping to capture.

Answer (score 2):

`|| true` should be outside the command substitution.

```
MYVAR=$(</some/file) || true
```

Your attempt failed because `$(<file)` is a special case, it doesn't work if there's anything else within the parantheses other than stdin redirection operator and the pathname.

Comment: While you are using Bash syntax, why not simply: `{ IFS= read -rd '' MYVAR </some/file || :;} 2>/dev/null`?

Comment: Because `$(<file)` syntax is very convenient. And I'm not really sure if OP wants to silence the error message

Answer (score 2):

The $(</file) syntax is a '[specific bash specialty](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst#specialities)'

If you change from that specific syntax, you just redirect into nothingness.

You either just use cat, or you wrap this specific syntax in a compound block:

```
{ MYVAR=$(</some/file); } 2>/dev/null
```