# commits wasnt submit in merge request with gitlab api

Tags: git, gitlab-api

From the GITLAB API documentation,I want to create several commits on a single branch,and after that create a merge request in bash script.

```
   curl -i --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: privatekey" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "$PAYLOAD" "https://hostgit/api/v4/projects/1234/repository/commits"
```

and about PAYLOAD

```
    PAYLOAD=$(cat << JSON 
{
  "branch": "mybranch",
  "commit_message": "some commit message",
  "actions": [
    {
      "action": "update",
      "file_path": "roles/test.j2"
    },
     {
          "action": "update",
      "file_path": "roles/prod.j2"
      }
  ]
}
JSON
)
```

script update the files so after this commit i use create MR but its an empty MR.why its empty ?? commit changes are 0.
also i use to content in actions a file path but its didn't work and commits still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `update` action, you have to specify the content of the file, and it should be the entire file content, not just the updated parts. Gitlab will then generate the diff and commit the changes correctly. You would need to update your payload so it looks something like:

```sh
PAYLOAD=$(cat << JSON
{
  "branch": "mybranch",
  "commit_message": "some commit message",
  "actions": [
    {
      "action": "update",
      "file_path": "roles/test.j2",
      "content": "this is the entire content in the test.j2 file after updating it"
    },
    {
      "action": "update",
      "file_path": "roles/prod.j2",
      "content": "This is the entire content in the prod.j2 file after updating it"
    }
  ]
}
JSON
)
```

You can see all the optional and required parameters in [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#create-a-commit-with-multiple-files-and-actions).
]

Comment: thanks ,the files are firewall roles with 100 lines i cant put entire file in content !!! and i want make the commit and merge automate in script ,how can i do this?

Comment: According to the docs, that's the only way to update a file via the API. Otherwise, you can always use `git`.

Comment: so i cant use api i  guess in this case its better to use command line  git commit and push in script.thank you

Comment: You can use the API, but you have to send the files entire content. If that’s difficult due to file size, you can use got instead.

Comment: yes difficult , its 100 lines in file ,how i must do that?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10771857/2307873)  shows a good way to get a file’s contents into a variable which you can then use when hitting the api.