# How can I read a file into a variable in bash

Tags: bash, double-quotes

I want to store the contents of a file in a bash shell variable. This works fine:

```
$ cat hello
Hello, world!
$ F=hello
$ Q=$(cat $F)
$ echo $Q
Hello, world!
```

However, if the file contains an asterisk, the asterisk is replaced by a list of all files in the current directory.

How can I quote the filename to protect the asterisk? Or otherwise load the file into the shell variable?

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427262/how-to-read-a-file-into-a-variable-in-shell), but it doesn't work for files that contain an asterisk.

Comment: The next question: what if the _filename_ contains a space? `mv hello "hello world"; F="hello world"` -- what happens when you do `Q=$(cat $F)` ?

Comment: Note, bash has a builtin way to read a file into a variable: `Q=$(<"$F")` -- documented in [3.5.4 Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)

Comment: Always run problem scripts through https://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Q` contains the asterisk. It is the *unquoted* expansion of `$Q` that replaces the `*` with a list of files.

```
$ Q="*"
$ echo $Q
<list of files>
$ echo "$Q"
*
```

The right-hand side of an assignment is not subject to path name expansion, so `Q=*` would work as well, and the command substitution used to read from the file is also not affected. `Q=$(cat hello)` works fine: you  just need to quote the expansion of `Q`.