# How to keep the previous value of a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I made a little program to manage the brightness of the screen for my laptop.
the problem is that when i overwrite the BRIGHTNESSCTRL variable, well, i overwrite it and the previous value is erased, so when i use the program always it sets the brightness to 20000, any help is appreciated.
By the way this is my program.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Actual brightness:' ; cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness 

cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness > BRIGHTNESSCTRL

let "BRIGHTNESSCTRL=BRIGHTNESSCTRL+10000"

if [[ $BRIGHTNESSCTRL -gt 96000 ]] ; then BRIGHTNESSCTRL=96000 ; fi && echo 'Success' || echo 'Failure' 

echo $BRIGHTNESSCTRL

sudo echo $BRIGHTNESSCTRL > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness ; echo $BRIGHTNESSCTRL
```

Comment: See [How to read a file into a variable in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427262/how-to-read-a-file-into-a-variable-in-shell)

Comment: Where do you set variable BRIGHTNESSCTRL with a value? `> BRIGHTNESSCTRL` redirects output to a file named BRIGHTNESSCTRL.

Comment: how/when do you determine that the 'previous' value should be used? at the beginning of the script? upon initiating a new shell/session?  what happens if you run the script multiple times during the same shell/session ... which brightness setting would you expect to be used? assuming you know what the 'previous' value is(was), I'd probably opt for a variable to hold a 'default' value (perhaps add to your `.profile/.bashrc`), then modify this script to display the 'default' value as well as the 'current' value, perhaps give the user an option to pick one of the two or manually enter a 3rd value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing a file with a shell variable. The first command writes the original value to a file, but you are never reading that file.

Your question is rather unclear, but I guess you are looking for something like

```sh
#!/bin/bash
brightness=$(cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness)

echo "Actual brightness: $brightness"

brightness=$((brightness+10000))

if [[ $brightness -gt 96000 ]] ; then
    brightness=96000
fi

echo $brightness | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

It's unclear when you hoped `echo "Success"` or `echo "Failure"` to happen, so I took those out. Notice that `sudo` only provides privileged access to the individual command you run (in your case, that was `echo`), not to any redirections performed by the shell. You should [prefer lower case for private variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).

Comment: It seems like i was confused about the difference about assign the output to a var or to a file, i am a newbie in this, also the problem about redirecting i readed about it but i didn't realized the reason of the error, for avoid that error i changed the file permissions but i'll reset them and use 'tee' instead for overwrite instead of redirect the output indirectly, thank you pal :)