# Reading file content into variable in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to read a files content into a variable in my .sh.
Some part of the files path is stored in another variable.

This is my current code:

```
almvers=${cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/pom-almversion.txt}
```

But I get this error:

```
${cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/pom-almversion.txt}: bad substitution
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies the problem, and shows exactly how to fix it.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: `${ ... }` is for parameter expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `cat`.

---

Consider doing the following:

```
almvers="$(<$CI_PROJECT_DIR/pom-almversion.txt)"
```

Comment: Thanks, works now. I expected cat and < to do the same

Comment: Problem was the `${...}` where you need `$(...)`. Avoiding cat is an optimization, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749905/how-can-i-read-a-file-and-redirect-it-to-a-variable.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds a potential problem in the code (missing quotes).  The report includes a link to more information about the problem and how to fix it.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.